# powershell - how to run specific part of code several times

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0, powershell-remoting

if I want to run PS script several times, I can use windows scheduler, but what if I need to run several times certain part of code, not whole script?

I have script to monitor remote server and I need to check processor time every second and the amount of ram every minute. I don't want to split it to more separate scripts, because I'm monitoring dozens of values. Or do you have some different idea of resolvint that?

Thank you!

Comment: Are you using Get-Counter? http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849685.aspx

Comment: Yes, I'm using Get-Counter to get Processor time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You perhaps can use WMI timer for that

```
PS C:\> $iClsTimer = [wmiclass]"__IntervalTimerInstruction"
PS C:\> $iTimer = $iClsTimer.CreateInstance();
PS C:\> $iTimer.TimerId="MonEvtTimer"
PS C:\> $iTimer.IntervalBetweenEvents= 2000
PS C:\> $iTimer.SkipIfPassed=$true
PS C:\> $iTimer.Put()

Path          : \\.\root\cimv2:__IntervalTimerInstruction.TimerId="MonEvtTimer"
RelativePath  : __IntervalTimerInstruction.TimerId="MonEvtTimer"
Server        : .
NamespacePath : root\cimv2
ClassName     : __IntervalTimerInstruction
IsClass       : False
IsInstance    : True
IsSingleton   : False

PS C:\silogix> $query = "Select * From __TimerEvent Where TimerID='MonEvtTimer'"
PS C:\silogix> Register-WMIEvent -Query $query -Action {write-host "Timer"}

Id              Name            State      HasMoreData     Location       Command
--              ----            -----      -----------     --------       -------
2               19e70483-2a0... NotStarted False                          write-host "Timer"
```

**Remark** : Another solution is to use Windows Forms timer

Comment: Thank you JPBlanc, this looks useful. Now I don't know how to stop it in ISE:)....I have to switch to PowerGUI.

Comment: You can try Get-event | remove-Event